# How can I design my domain driven design in OO to accommodate attributes for different entities?

Tags: object, model, entity, domain-driven-design

**The problem**

I am creating an IP address management solution. I want to be able to add attributes to each object in my model. Before I go in further I will explain what an attribute is. An attribute is simply a name/value pair that we will associate to an object. For example:

**Network Object**
Attribute - Building=5
Attribute - Department=Sales

**Host Object**
Attribute - Building=5
Attribute - Department=Sales

The reason for adding attributes is to query the system to find out information. For example, which networks do we have in building 5 or find me all objects with an attribute that equals X.

**Design of DDD System**

The network is a model which is manipulated via a service. For example there is a network service which can perform a CRUD, it accepts a network object.

**Questions/Thoughts of adding attributes that span across multiple entities**

Assume I have an attribute collection (which includes the actual attribute in an array inside that collection object). This attribute collection will be added to my network.

Should we add every part of functionality for an attribute inside the service of every entity like the network?
Should we create a separate service for the attribute, but here I am not sure how we would manage the objects that require attributes for them?

The type of questions we want to ask the system with attributes:

Q: How do you get all entities with an attribute of X?

Now I don't want to think about the database as that is later on. I just want an idea on what we can do from the object level using Domain Driven Design.

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to have is a classification system.  It will in all probability be a sub domain.  I don't think you want to add this functionality to each domain aggregate root that requires classification.

In any event you do mention that it is used mainly for querying/finding objects.  I would go for a generic sub domain where you can select qualifying ARs from one or more BCs and then assign these additional attributes to the AR in the *Classification BC*.

You would then use the *Classification BC* to find the relevant Ids and additional information about the ARs you require and then navigate from there.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by AR and BC?

Comment: AR == Aggregate Root / BC == Bounded Context

Comment: Do you have any examples that may be similar to this?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have DDD examples of this.  I have done something similar years ago (not DDD) so the concept should be sound.